# Is $\mathbb{Q}\cap (-\infty,\pi)$ open in $\mathbb{R} $?

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb{Q}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ so surely $\mathbb{Q}\cap (-\infty,\pi)$ is not open.

However in the following hyperlink (a proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not connected on Proof Wiki) claims it is

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_not_Connected

Is it wrong? Or is this proof proving that $\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected in $\mathbb{Q}$? If so how can he/she just pick any irrational number when such a number is not defined in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The space there is $\Bbb Q$; i.e., the set $\Bbb Q$ with the subspace topology under $\Bbb R$. There, an open set is of the form $O\cap \Bbb R$ where $O$ is open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Towards the end of the proof it quite clearly states that $S := \mathbb Q \cap \left({-\infty, \alpha}\right)$ and $T := \mathbb Q \cap \left({\alpha, \infty}\right)$ are open sets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake made in the proof, and there are some things which are obviously a little unclear to you:

1. The proof is not proving that "$\mathbb Q$ is disconnected in $\mathbb Q$". There is no concept in topology that says that "$X$ is connected in $Y$". Being connected is a property of the **whole** space, and what this proof shows is that $\mathbb Q$, as a topological space, is *not* connected.
2. Your statement that $\mathbb Q\cap (-\infty, b)$ is not open because $\mathbb Q$ is not open is faulty. There is no rule in topology by which an intersection of two sets cannot be open if the two sets are not open. For example, $[0,1)\cap (0,1]=(0,1)$ is an open set, even though none of the sets it is an intersection of is open.
3. Just because the number $a$ is not a rational number, that does not mean it cannot be used in the construction of a subset of rational numbers. $a$ may be any number, rational or not, and $\mathbb Q\cap (-\infty, a)$  will be a subset of rational numbers.

That said, the proof is perfectly fine. It is pa proof that shows the following statement:

> There exist two sets, $S$ and $T$, which have the following properties:
>
> - They are both subsets of $\mathbb Q$
> - They are both open in $\mathbb Q$ (with the standard euclidean topology)
> - Their intersection is empty ($S\cap T = \emptyset$)
> - Their union is $\mathbb Q$ ($S\cup T = \mathbb Q$)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is saying that $\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\infty,\pi)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathbb{R}$ plays no rôle apart from containing the number $\pi$, whereas $\mathbb{Q}$ does not. You need this because every rational number is at finite distance from $\pi$, so you can always find the balls it constructs in $\mathbb{Q}$, which contain $x$ and do not escape from $\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\infty,\pi)$.

You can do it another way, without reference to $\mathbb{R}$, if you choose an $a$ that is easier to describe, such as the set $ \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : x^3 < 2 \}$. Since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational, this is a set of the form $\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\infty,a)$, but described only in terms of $\mathbb{Q}$. ($a$ being $\sqrt[3]{2}$ here, of course.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful. However I still struggle to understand that if we are only in the space $\mathbb{Q}$ why are we allowed to use irrational numbers? I thought they weren't necessarily defined?

Comment: @Eclipse: The irrational numbers _do exist_. You're constructing a set that doesn't _contain_ any of them, but that doesn't mean you can't use them for purposes _other than_ as members of the set you construct.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Q\cap(-\infty,\pi)$ is not open in $\mathbb R$ -- but it *is* open in $\mathbb Q$.

In contrast to "open", "connected" is something a single topological space either is or isn't. There's no such thing as "$Y$ is connected in $X$", it is just whether or not $X$ is connected.

If $Y$ is a subset of $X$ we can equip it with the subset topology, which makes $Y$ into a topological space in its own right; then we can ask whether $Y$ is connected.

> If so how can he/she just pick any irrational number when such a number is not defined in $\mathbb Q$?

The proof lives in a world where the real numbers do exist. It proves something *about* $\mathbb Q$ which doesn't *contain* irrational numbers, but that doesn't mean that we need to pretend they don't exist at all. We can use any technique available to us for constructing a subset of $\mathbb Q$ when we need it.